# Docker's containers communication using Consul

Tags: docker, consul

I have read about service discovery for Docker using Consul, but I can't understand it.

Could you explain to me, how can I run two docker containers, recognize from the first container host of the second using Consul and send some message to it?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to run [Consul Agent](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html) in client mode inside each Docker container. Each Docker Container will need a [Consul Service Definition](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html) file to let the Agent know to advertize it's service to the Consul Servers.

They look like this:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "redis",
    "tags": ["master"],
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 8000,
    "checks": [
      {
        "script": "/usr/local/bin/check_redis.py",
        "interval": "10s"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And a [Service Health Check](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html) to monitor the health of the service. Something like this:

```
{
  "check": {
    "id": "redis",
    "name": "Redis",
    "script": "/usr/local/bin/check_redis_ping_returns_pong.sh",
    "interval": "10s"
  }
}
```

In the other Docker Container your code would find the Redis service either via DNS or the Consul Servers HTTP API

```
dig @localhost -p 8500 redis.service.consul

curl $CONSUL_SERVER/v1/health/service/redis?passing
```

Comment: When you say "inside each Docker container", do you really mean that a different application container should also be running the consul agent? I don't think that's necessary, and goes against the principle of separate containers for separate tasks.

Comment: @VinceBowdren depends on how you want to do it, and what you think of as a task. If it fits better for you to run consul on the slave or in another container and expose it's agent into the container that is fine. but the service registration and health check are cohesive to the container that runs the application binary, so I would favor moving those files around in the container they are crafted for.